# Return only selected page from IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application. Currently its running on trial basis.
I update it frequently in a day.

While I update the site, I need to show users "index.html" which tells users that site is updating.

It's not a problem when a new user comes to that domain **www.mysite.com**.

But, current user who is on **www.mysite.com/other/somelink** and tries to go another link gets page not found error.

Is there any way to redirect him only to index.html ?

Please note that, during update, I delete all from root and put there index.html.

Comment: Put this file instead of index.html: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/426755

Comment: @CodeCaster Your suggestion works. Post it as answer. So that i can accept it.

Comment: No, it's already an answer to the same question. :-) I won't repost answers. Vote to close if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an `App_Offline.htm` page to the root directory. All done.

Comment: Don't answer duplicate questions, especially not when OP has confirmed it's a duplicate. Flag to close the question as a duplicate (of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819184/how-to-show-maintenance-page-during-deployment)) instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster Got it. But i already did it. So what to do now?